# CSS transitions not working in IE-11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, css-transitions

I have a scenario where on button click transition should happen

```
transition-property: top, left;
transition-duration: 10s;
transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-property: top, left;
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-moz-transition-property: top, left;
-moz-transition-duration: 2s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0s;
-ms-transition-property: top, left;
-ms-transition-duration: 2s;
-ms-transition-delay: 0s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
```

These are the transitions which were applied .In chrome browser it is working good, but in IE-11 when tried the transitions aren't getting applied.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add proper code or working fiddle.

Comment: Your meta tag : <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1"/>   ?????

Answer (score 1):

If you have any meta tag please check it's on your meta same to 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>`
on not same check it. Thank you.

Comment: I have a meta tag like: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Comment: please re write this and check : <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>